# Android minify end up with ktor not deserializing nested objects

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, minify, ktor

I tired to activate minifying in my android project with the code below

```
release {
            isDebuggable = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
```

My proguard file contains only one line to try avoid any issue with ktor `-keep class io.ktor.** { *; }`

However deserialization of nested object is not working.

Here is my api class

```
class ApiImplem @Inject constructor() : IApi {

    private val client = HttpClient {
        default()
        defaultRequest {
            url(BuildConfig.API_URL)
            header("X-Api-Key", BuildConfig.API_KEY)
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getUserInfo(accessToken: String): UserInfoResponse =
        client.get("/auth/user-info") {
            bearerAuth(accessToken)
        }.body()
}

fun HttpClientConfig<*>.default() {
    install(HttpCookies)

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
            setPrettyPrinting()
            disableHtmlEscaping()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my data class

```
@Serializable
data class UserInfoResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val email: String,
    val phone: String,
    val client: ClientResponse,
)

@Serializable
data class ClientResponse(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val socialReason: String,
    val siren: String,
    val address: String,
)
```

With minify disabled everything works perfectly but as soon as I enable minify, my nested object client is not parsed anymore and remains null.

If I try to log the object returned by the `getUserInfo` function I got `UserInfoResponse(id=1, name=Name, email=email@test.com, phone=0100000000, client=null)` whereas my api response is `{"id":1,"name":"Name","email":"email@test.com","phone":"0100000000","client":{"id":1,"name":"Client","socialReason":"CLIENT","siren":"123456789","address":"ADDRESS"}}`

Does anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong or what I should add to my proguard file to avoid this issue ?

Comment: In Java I use `@Keep` to prevent proguard from changing the class, I think it is also available in Kotlin.